# Using GA4 server-side to get the client_id without an html file (server-side)

Tags: google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol, gtag.js

## Problem

I'm trying to send GA4 events from an application that only has voice UI - there is **no html file** - thus no where to inject the necessary scripts to install GA4, as per the [Google install documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/install). I have all of the events set up - however, I don't know how to get and pass in the Client ID per voice assistant device (Alexa) that we would need to successfully send the analytics events and params.

## Attempt to fix

What I've attempted to do is use the [jsdom npm package](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#loading-subresources) to set something up like this -

```js
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!doctype html>
        <head>
            <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxx"></script>
            <script>
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){
                    dataLayer.push(arguments)
                }
                gtag('js', new Date());
            
                gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXX');
                gtag('get', 'G-XXXXXX', 'client_id', (clientID) => {
                    console.log(clientID)
                    globalThis.clientId = clientID
                    return clientID
                });
            </script>
        </head>
    </html>
`, { runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" });

if (typeof dom.window !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(dom.window.dataLayer);
}
```

When I log the results (i just run node my-file.ts to test this), we do have data in the dataLayer with the arguments passed into gtag() -

```js
[
  [Arguments] { '0': 'js', '1': 2024-01-24T16:46:22.068Z },
  [Arguments] { '0': 'config', '1': 'G-XXXXXX' },
  [Arguments] {
    '0': 'get',
    '1': 'G-XXXXXX',
    '2': 'client_id',
    '3': [Function (anonymous)]
  }
]
```

[Function (anonymous)] is where I would expect the clientID to log, save to a global variable, and return.

So, what happens when we call the anonymous function, like so

`console.log(dom.window.dataLayer[2][3]());` ?

This logs `undefined`.
The value of client_id is also `undefined`.

I understand that we're just passing in arguments to gtag() that don't really *do* anything.

So, how would I get the clientID and access to the gtag() function in a 'headless' environment? Is it even possible? Am I doing something incorrectly that doesn't first render the javascript from the googletagmanager.com/gtag url before we set up the other script?